# Compactness and cartesian product

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, compactness

I'm having trouble figuring out how can I show that if two sets are compact then their cartesian product is also compact.

Any help is much appreciated,thank you!

Comment: I would try open covers instead but that's just me.

Comment: You can also use convergent subsequences.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: There is an $r\in\Bbb R$ such that $X\cup Y\subseteq[-r,r]$; why? What can you say about $X\times Y$ and $[-r,r]^2$? For closedness, think about the set $(\Bbb R\setminus X)\times\Bbb R$, among others.

(As noted in the comments, you can use just about any characterization of compactness to prove this result without enormous difficulty; I’ve simply chosen the one that you already had in mind.)

Comment: Is this because the union of two bounded sets is bounded?

Comment: And how does closedness follow?

Comment: @user196170: $[-r,r]^2$ is bounded (why?), so any subset of it is bounded. $(\Bbb R\setminus X)\times\Bbb R$ is open, and so is $\Bbb R\times(\Bbb R\setminus Y)$. The union of two open sets is open; what’s the union of these two sets? And the complement of an open set is closed.

Comment: thank you so much!! I understand how closeness follows, but I don't see why [-r,r]^2 is bounded. It makes intuitive sense but I can't figure out how to prove it

Comment: @user196170: That square is contained in a closed disk centred at the origin, which by definition makes it bounded. Can you find (in terms of $r$) a radius big enough to work? HINT: Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: thanks a lot! This was very helpful.

Comment: @user196170: You’re welcome!